# “List indices must be integers, not str” for Bing Search

Tags: python

Hey im new to programming in python. I have a program which gets urls from bing search. It's supposed to print the urls in the last two lines of code. Yet it gives the error mentioned above.

```
import requests
URL = "https://mykey:mykey@api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?$format=json&Query=%(query)s"
API_KEY = 'mykey'

def request(query, **params):
    query = ('%27'+query+ '%27')
    r = requests.get(URL % {'query': query}, auth=('', API_KEY))
    print r.content
    return [res['Url'] for res in r.json()['d']['results']]


r = request("Jason Bourne")

for res in r['d']['results']:
        print res['Url']
```

The error is for the second last line 
How can i fix the code?

Here's the traceback

```
for res in r['d']['results']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Could you edit your traceback (error) into the post?

Comment: At some point in your logic, you are attempting to traverse a list, which you assume to be a dictionary. Assuming the response is serialized as JSON... import json... json.loads(response)

Answer (score 1):

In your `request` method, you already unpack the json dictionary into a list using that comprehension.  So `r` just looks like `['some url', 'some other url', 'some third url']`.

When you try to unpack the list in the same way that you unpacked `r.json()`, an exception is raised since that doesn't really make sense.  You can access the list members with

```
for url in a:
    print url
```

or just `print a` if you don't care about the formatting.

Optionally just `return r.json()` from your `request` method, if you want callers to have access to the whole dict.

Comment: Well i essentially need each and every url as i need it for other processes. Can you suggest how i can print each url, by making necessarily changes.

Comment: @user2675675 I.. just explained that.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this Python function will return a URL-fetched json document in dict format

```
import json
import requests

def query_site(url, params):    # Psuedo code def()... Depends on the site's API

    r = requests.get(url, params=params)   # Psuedo code... Depends on the site's API

    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        return r.json()     # Per Roippi, this bit of code returns a type that Python can use as 'dict'
    else:
        r.raise_for_status()
```

After calling this function  do a `type(r)` and you'll get "dict."